# Issue Nextjs ecommerce, showing all orders not that of user's only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, next.js, next.js13

like the title says i've  this problem in my ecommerce built with next.js in typescript. I got a route with a GET request, i got trough redux the _id of the user logged,but in the component that showing the user's order he got all the orders, not only his.
here's the code in the backend:

// orders/route.ts

```
import { connectDB } from "@/configs/dbConfig";
import { NextResponse, NextRequest } from "next/server";
import Order from "@/models/orderModel";
import { validateJWT } from "@/helpers/validateJWT";

connectDB();

export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  try {
    await validateJWT(request);
    const searchParams = new URL(request.nextUrl).searchParams;
    const { user }: any = searchParams;
    const filters: any = {};
    if (user) filters["user"] = user;
    const orders = await Order.find(filters).populate("user", "name email");
    return NextResponse.json(orders);
  } catch (error: any) {
    return NextResponse.json({ message: error.message }, { status: 500 });
  }
}
```

here is the component refering to the frontend

// UserOrdersList.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Modal, Table, message } from "antd";
import moment from "moment";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

function UserOrdersList() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [loading = false, setLoading] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const [showCancelModal = false, setShowCancelModal] =
    React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const [selectedOrder, setSelectedOrder] = React.useState<any>(null);
  const [statusUpdateLoading = false, setStatusUpdateLoading] =
    React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const [orders = [], setOrders] = React.useState([]);
  const { currentUser } = useSelector((state: any) => state.user);

  const getOrders = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const endPoint = `/api/orders?user=${currentUser._id}`;
      const response = await axios.get(endPoint);
      console.log(response.data);
      setOrders(response.data);
    } catch (error: any) {
      message.error(error.message);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const onStatusUpdate = async (orderId: string, status: string) => {
    try {
      setStatusUpdateLoading(true);
      const endPoint = `/api/orders/${orderId}`;
      await axios.put(endPoint, { orderStatus: status });
      message.success("Your order has been cancelled successfully , Thank you");
      setShowCancelModal(false);
      getOrders();
    } catch (error: any) {
      message.error(error.response.data.message);
    } finally {
      setStatusUpdateLoading(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getOrders();
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  const columns = [
    {
      title: "Order ID",
      dataIndex: "_id",
    },
    {
      title: "Placed On",
      dataIndex: "createdAt",
      render: (date: string) => moment(date).format("DD MMM YYYY hh:mm a"),
    },
    {
      title: "Total",
      dataIndex: "total",
    },
    {
      title: "Status",
      dataIndex: "orderStatus",
      render: (status: string) => status.toUpperCase(),
    },
    {
      title: "Action",
      render: (record: any) => (
        <div className="flex gap-5">
          {record.orderStatus === "order placed" && (
            <span
              className="underline cursor-pointer"
              onClick={() => {
                setSelectedOrder(record);
                setShowCancelModal(true);
              }}
            >
              Cancel
            </span>
          )}
          <span
            className="underline cursor-pointer"
            onClick={() => {
              router.push(`/profile/orders/${record._id}`);
            }}
          >
            View
          </span>
        </div>
      ),
    },
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      <Table
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={orders}
        rowKey="_id"
        loading={loading}
        pagination={false}
      />

      {selectedOrder && (
        <Modal
          open={showCancelModal}
          onCancel={() => {
            setShowCancelModal(false);
          }}
          title="Cancel Order"
          centered
          closable={false}
          onOk={() => {
            onStatusUpdate(selectedOrder._id, "cancelled");
          }}
          okText="Yes, Cancel Order"
          cancelText="No, Keep Order"
          okButtonProps={{
            loading: statusUpdateLoading,
          }}
        >
          <p className="my-10 text-gray-600">
            Are you sure you want to cancel order #{selectedOrder._id} ? This
            action cannot be undone.
          </p>
        </Modal>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default UserOrdersList;
```

even if i fetch the data from /api/orders i get all the orders.

Comment: Debug 1: Is `currentUser ` being set properly ? // Debug 2: Do you get the correct orders if you browse `/api/orders?user=${currentUser._id}` by manually adding the current user ID ?

Comment: I get all the orders not the user’s ones. Do i ve to set the route or can I somehow filter the data fetched in the frontend component?

Comment: Assuming you have no control over the API backend, and there's no specific route for that, then yes, your only option is to filter on the frontend. (Perhaps using array filter)

Comment: Yes I did in this way, I filtered the data fetched and make go to screen the only ones is releated to the current user. Done ✔️